# FMDB query with char

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

I'm currently trying to execute a query on a database of words. The database is organized such that I can access by first letter of the word, and by length of the word. However, I'm having trouble when I search using a letter and length:

```
//random letter sends an NSString with just a single letter from the English alphabet
NSString * randomLetter = [self randomLetter];
int characterCodeInASCII = [randomLetter characterAtIndex:0];

FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE INDEXER=? AND LENGTH=?",characterCodeInASCII,length];
```

Unfortunately, the query isn't returning any values. I've tried this using a char as the input, as a string, and as an int.

I'm quite confused since I can do the same query using ruby:

```
list=db1.execute("SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE INDEXER=110 AND LENGTH=7")
```

And get 453 results....

The sqlite table has the following columns:

```
>> db1.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master")
=> [["table", "words", "words", 2, "CREATE TABLE words(word VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY, indexer VARCHAR(1), length INTEGER)"], ["index", "sqlite_autoindex_words_1", "words", 3, nil]]
```

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FMDB is expecting all of the arguments to the `executeQuery:` method to be objects, and an `int` isn't an object.

There are a couple of approaches you could take:

1. Box the `int` in an `NSNumber`.  That would look like this:

   ```
   NSString *randomLetter = ...;
   NSNumber *characterCode = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[randomLetter characterAtIndex:0]];

   NSNumber *length = [NSNumber numberWithInt:lengthAsInt];
   FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE INDEXER=? AND LENGTH=?", characterCode, length];
   ```
2. Use a different method, such as the `executeQueryWithFormat:` method:

   ```
   FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE INDEXER = %d AND LENGTH + %d", characterCodeInASCII, length];
   ```

Comment: Ahh! Okay, I didn't realize that it takes objects for the standard executeQuery call <smacks head for not looking at doc closer>. Thank you, I ended up using the second approach and it works great!